Perl Array Access to values for update process in MySQL
In OCSInventory I want to use a DataFilter in order to bypass Classic Inventory Process and treat my XML entries the way I want.
HereUnder is the code updated according to @choroba comments.
If it can be used by anybody else :)
###############################################################################
## 
## Version : 3.0
## 
## Usage : to adapt this script quickly search for the "TO DO" String
##
###############################################################################
package Apache::Ocsinventory::Plugins::Dbinstance::DataFilterDbinstance; ## TO DO

use strict;

BEGIN {
    if($ENV{'OCS_MODPERL_VERSION'} == 1) {
        require Apache::Ocsinventory::Server::Modperl1;
        Apache::Ocsinventory::Server::Modperl1->import();
    } elsif($ENV{'OCS_MODPERL_VERSION'} == 2) {
        require Apache::Ocsinventory::Server::Modperl2;
        Apache::Ocsinventory::Server::Modperl2->import();
    }
}

use Apache::Ocsinventory::Server::System;
use Apache::Ocsinventory::Server::Communication;
use Apache::Ocsinventory::Server::Constants;
use Apache::Ocsinventory::Interface::Database;
use Apache::Ocsinventory::Map;

# Initialize option
push @{$Apache::Ocsinventory::OPTIONS_STRUCTURE}, {
    'NAME' => 'DATAFILTER',
    'HANDLER_PROLOG_READ' => undef, #or undef # Called before reading the prolog
    'HANDLER_PROLOG_RESP' => undef, #or undef # Called after the prolog response building
    'HANDLER_PRE_INVENTORY' => \&dbinstance_pre_inventory, ## TO DO Change Method Name
    'HANDLER_POST_INVENTORY' => undef, #or undef # Called when inventory is stored without error
    'REQUEST_NAME' => undef,  #or undef # Value of <QUERY/> xml tag
    'HANDLER_REQUEST' => undef, #or undef # function that handle the request with the <QUERY>'REQUEST NAME'</QUERY>
    'HANDLER_DUPLICATE' => undef,#or undef # Called when a computer is handle as a duplicate
    'TYPE' => OPTION_TYPE_SYNC, # or OPTION_TYPE_ASYNC ASYNC=>with pr without inventory, SYNC=>only when inventory is required
    'XML_PARSER_OPT' => {
        'ForceArray' => ['']
    }
};

sub _prepare_and_run_sql {
    my ($sql, @arguments) = @_;
    my $query;
    my $i = 1;
    
    my $dbh = $Apache::Ocsinventory::CURRENT_CONTEXT{'DBI_HANDLE'};
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    foreach my $value (@arguments) {
        if(defined $value) {
            $query->bind_param($i, $value);
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $query->execute or return undef; 

    return $query;
}


sub dbinstance_pre_inventory { ## TO DO change method name
    &_log(1,'datafilterDbinstance',"pre_process") if $ENV{'OCS_OPT_LOGLEVEL'};

    my $tableandXML="DBINSTANCE";## TO DO Set this value to the common Database and XML tags names
    my $current_context = shift;
    our $xml = $current_context->{'XML_ENTRY'};
    my $hardware_id = $Apache::Ocsinventory::CURRENT_CONTEXT{'DATABASE_ID'};
    my @id_to_delete;
    my @column_paramaters;
    my @arguments_update_array=();
    my @arguments_not_to_be_deleted;
    my @arguments_insert;
    foreach my $session (@{$xml->{CONTENT}->{$tableandXML}}) {
        ## Look at an already existing entry in the database to define if entry will be an update or an insert
        my $update_query = "SELECT * FROM `$tableandXML` WHERE HARDWARE_ID=? AND UID=? GROUP BY UID HAVING COUNT(*)=1 ;";
        my @arguments_update=();
        my @arguments=();
        my $update_result = _prepare_and_run_sql($update_query, @update_arg);
        my $update_row = $update_result->fetchrow_hashref();
            ## TO DO Set the variables that will be used according to the XML entry
            push @arguments, $hardware_id;
            push @arguments, $session->{NAME};
            push @arguments, $session->{TYPE};
            push @arguments, $session->{SERVER_NAME};
            push @arguments, $session->{SERVER_BINARY_PATH};
            push @arguments, $session->{PORT};
            push @arguments, $session->{STATE};
            push @arguments, $session->{UID};
            push @arguments, $session->{SERVER_UID};
            push @arguments, $session->{SERVER_VERSION};
            push @arguments, $session->{EXECUTIONDATE};
                
            if($update_row) { ## part for the update. Used when there is a result to the update query request. In this case we have to perform an update
                ## define the update query arguments
                for my $value(@arguments){
                    if(length($value)) { push @arguments_update, $value; } else { push @arguments_update, ""; }
                }
                push @arguments_update, $update_row->{ID};
                push @arguments_not_to_be_deleted, $update_row->{ID}; ## As the entry will be updated we add it to the results that should not be deleted
                # my $update_query = "UPDATE `$tableandXML` SET HARDWARE_ID=?, NAME=?, TYPE=?, SERVER_NAME=?, SERVER_BINARY_PATH=?, PORT=?, STATE=?, UID=?, SERVER_UID=?, SERVER_VERSION=?, EXECUTIONDATE=? WHERE ID=?; "; ## Define the query
                # my $update_result = _prepare_and_run_sql($update_query, @arguments_update);  ## Play the query with the previously defined arguments

            push (@arguments_update_array, @arguments_update);
            }
        else{ ##If the XML entry is not present in the database then it is an insert
            push @column_paramaters, "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; ## Define the number of fields to bee created
            for my $value(@arguments){
                if(length($value)) { push @arguments_insert, $value; } else { push @arguments_insert, ""; }
            }
        }
    }
    # ## Perform the updates
    for (my $i=0; $i < @arguments_update_array; $i++) {
        my @arguments_update_final = @{$arguments_update_array[$i]};
        my $update_query = "UPDATE `$tableandXML` SET HARDWARE_ID=?, NAME=?, TYPE=?, SERVER_NAME=?, SERVER_BINARY_PATH=?, PORT=?, STATE=?, UID=?, SERVER_UID=?, SERVER_VERSION=?, EXECUTIONDATE=? WHERE ID=?; "; ## TO DO Define the query using the same order as previously defined
        my $update_result = _prepare_and_run_sql($update_query, @arguments_update_final);  ## Play the query with the previously defined arguments
    }

    ## Once updates have been performed or no updates have been done. We delete all the last existing entries
    my $arrSize = @arguments_not_to_be_deleted;
    my $verif_query;
    if($arrSize eq 0){ ## Case where not any updated element. We delete all entries.
    $verif_query = "DELETE FROM `$tableandXML` WHERE HARDWARE_ID=?;";
    }else{ ## Case where there are updated elements. We delete all entries except these ones
    $verif_query = "DELETE FROM `$tableandXML` WHERE HARDWARE_ID=? AND ID NOT IN ( ";
    $verif_query .= join ",", @arguments_not_to_be_deleted;
    $verif_query .= ")";
    }
    my $verif_result = _prepare_and_run_sql($verif_query, $hardware_id);
    if(defined $verif_result) { 
        while(my $row = $verif_result->fetchrow_hashref()) {
            push @id_to_delete, $row->{ID};
        }
    }
    
    ## Then we insert new entries
    if(@arguments_insert) {
        my $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `$tableandXML`(HARDWARE_ID, NAME, TYPE, SERVER_NAME, SERVER_BINARY_PATH, PORT, STATE, UID, SERVER_UID, SERVER_VERSION, EXECUTIONDATE) VALUES "; ## TO DO Define the query using the same order as previously defined
        $insert_query .= join ",", @column_paramaters;
        my $insert_result = _prepare_and_run_sql($insert_query, @arguments_insert);
    }
    
    
    ## Finally we erase the DBINSTANCE XML entry for inventory process
    $current_context->{'XML_ENTRY'}->{CONTENT}->{$tableandXML}="";
    
    &_log(1,'datafilterDbinstance',"end:dbinstancepre_process") if $ENV{'OCS_OPT_LOGLEVEL'};
    ##And we relaunch the inventory process
    return INVENTORY_CONTINUE;

}

1;


Error appears during the perform process when trying to access the update_arrays for performing SQL statement
I tried a lot of syntax but on some cases httpd does not start and when it starts the main error I have is the following
[Tue Jun 04 07:38:35.748598 2024] [perl:error] [pid 1770] [client 10.221.32.16:58748] Can't use string ("17") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /busapps/t4ic/gbl0/ocscommunicationserver/perl/Apache/Ocsinventory/Plugins/Dbinstance/DataFilterDbinstance.pm line 118.\n
[Tue Jun 04 07:44:00.711280 2024] [perl:error] [pid 1771] [client 10.221.32.16:59406] Can't use string ("17") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /busapps/t4ic/gbl0/ocscommunicationserver/perl/Apache/Ocsinventory/Plugins/Dbinstance/DataFilterDbinstance.pm line 118.\n
[Tue Jun 04 07:51:22.770666 2024] [perl:error] [pid 5020] [client 10.221.32.16:60306] Can't use string ("446") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /busapps/t4ic/gbl0/ocscommunicationserver/perl/Apache/Ocsinventory/Plugins/Dbinstance/DataFilterDbinstance.pm line 118.\n
[Tue Jun 04 08:02:33.891894 2024] [perl:error] [pid 5021] [client 10.221.32.16:33376] Can't use string ("446") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /busapps/t4ic/gbl0/ocscommunicationserver/perl/Apache/Ocsinventory/Plugins/Dbinstance/DataFilterDbinstance.pm line 118.\n

EDIT : Lines 116-121, perform process :
# ## Perform the updates
    for (my $i=0; $i < @arguments_update_array; $i++) {
        my @arguments_update_final = @{ $arguments_update_array->[$i] };
        my $update_query = "UPDATE `$tableandXML` SET HARDWARE_ID=?, NAME=?, TYPE=?, SERVER_NAME=?, SERVER_BINARY_PATH=?, PORT=?, STATE=?, UID=?, SERVER_UID=?, SERVER_VERSION=?, EXECUTIONDATE=? WHERE ID=?; "; ## Define the query
        my $update_result = _prepare_and_run_sql($update_query, @arguments_update_final);  ## Play the query with the previously defined arguments
    }


What is line 118?

original post edited, sorry

The program pushes various things into @arguments_update_array:
if(length($value)) {
    push @arguments_update_array, $value;
} else {
    push @arguments_update, "";
}

or
push @arguments_update_array, $update_row->{ID};

or even
push (@arguments_update_array, \@arguments_update);

Only the last line pushes an array reference. You can't dereference all the elements of the array, as the ones created by the first two code parts will be scalars, not array references.
# The following is possible only if $arguments_update_array->[$i] is an array ref.
my @arguments_update_final = @{ $arguments_update_array->[$i] };


Thanks to you I've updated my code because arguments were pushed while they shouldn't have been. Thanks  a lot
